# The best design for notification box when there is multiple kind of notifications

Tags: website-design, gui-design, interaction-design

I have a Q&A website exactly like StackOverflow. Now I'm trying to create a box for notifications. My question isn't about programming, I just want to know your opinion about the UI design.

As you know, SO has two different box for *comments* and *votes*. My website has just one box for all kind of notifications. So all rows don't have an identical structure. Here is what I've designed so far:

[image]

I just want to know your opinion about the structure of those two rows. Just the structure, not the color, font, size etc .. . Just tell me is that structure user-friendly and delightful?

As you see, first kind of row has a separator and a score like this `| +2`, But the second kind of row doesn't have that separator, but it has a short part of the content like this: `this is a test content, ..`.

Ok, so what's your opinion about the UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the following :

- Remove the label "vote" and the seperator. They are reduntant elements.
- Place the vote and the title on the same line.
- Remove the label "comment".
- Use mouse over tooltip for the vote/comment icons.

[image]

Comment: Does an orange triangle effectively communicate this is a vote?

Comment: Thx  . . . +1  ..!